# Moved file error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter 2. I have moved the config folder and few others from application to a new folder in system called engine but now getting error error can not find catalog/config/constants.php I am trying to find out how to set the appropriate application and system paths in index.php?

So the file structure looks like this now

```
application<-- now named catalog
catalog > controllers
catalog > models
catalog > language
catalog > views
```

all other files that were in the catalog have now been moved in to

```
system >
system > engine
```

but do not know what I need to put in the index.php or change other files slowly learning it just need help to get around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a beginer I recommend you to leave the structure as it is. And only add files to the controller, model and view folders.